# How to implement a video exporter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, video, codec

I am implementing an online video editing platform, as a part of which, the users edit their videos online, and then export the edited video either in native format (suppose `.xyz`) or other standard video file formats like `.mp4`, `.mov`, `.avi` etc.

My question is: how should I go about implementing the video exporting part? I looked it up around the internet, and found some interesting topics that might be of use, like [video web codecs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Video_codecs) and [lossless compression](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-do-a-lossless-compression-to-a-video-file) of video files.

I am implementing the backend of the application in [Spring](https://spring.io), and I am a complete beginner in these areas.

Any help on how I should get started and implement this video file exporter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend the FFMPEG for video operations. One of my projects, I have used spring boot and ffmpeg in docker containers. Spring boot generated the command and ffmpeg did whole process.

Comment: @İsmailDurmaz Yeah, I can use FFMPEG for the video operations. I actually wanted to know how I can convert native video files into the standard ones and vice versa, or is that possible to be done by FFMPEG? (sorry, but I am quite new here!) 
Also, can you please explain a bit more about how you used Spring Boot and FFMPEG in your project?